# Upload C# project to FTP server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, ftp

I have a C# .NET website I have been trying to upload to a web hosting provider's servers.  I am successful if I upload the website to my base directory `http://www.xyz.org/hello.aspx`. But when I attempt to upload to a subdirectory `http://www.xyz.org/subDir/hello.aspx`, I get the below error message. I have a feeling it has to do with the config file? But I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> Parser Error
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The file '/Resume_MasterPage.master' does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ page title="" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Resume_MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="HomePage, App_Web_zotcvohv" %> 
> Line 2:  <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Resume_MasterPage.master" %> 
> Line 3:

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the translate of the location of the files. The `~` on this variable for example:

`masterpagefile="~/Resume_MasterPage.master"`

says that the `Resume_MasterPage.master` is located on the root, and not on a subdirectory, because the `~` is "translated" to the root path when is actually looking for the file.

Now you move it to a subdirectory and file can not be found.

I do not know if the site will actually work on the subdirectory, but the fist step is to remove the `~` from all that reference and make sure that work at last local. Maybe some other appears, but actually this is your issue.

Comment: Would I remove the '~' or would I add the subdirectory in the path name ... '~/subdir/Resume_MasterPage.master'

Comment: Line 1:  <%@ master language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Resume_MasterPage" %>

Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 Source File:  /cs/Resume_MasterPage.master    Line:  1 
Still getting error message unfortunately

Comment: @Chris Make a test - If you just remove it you must place them on the same directory. Error message ? what error ?

Comment: Hi Aristos, you are correct.  I deleted the error message when pasting in to comment sections.  I wanted to place more than one .net web project onto the same server (one in the root directory, and the others in sub directories).  Since I am still getting error messages.
<br/>
After I could not get the above to work, I thought I would try to add the web projects which were to be in subdirectories to the main/root web .net project while in visual studios.

Comment: This after I had all three webproject built in one main .net website project ... I could then upload the entire site (subdirectories and all) to the server.  The project loads fine when I execute off of visual studio (I can see the web pages in the root directory as we  as the web pages in the sub-directories) ... but once the project is uploaded onto the server you can view the pages in the root directory but again ... not in the subdirectories.

Comment: Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'HomePage'.

Source Error: 



Line 1:  <%@ page title="" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Resume_MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="HomePage" %>
Line 2:  <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Resume_MasterPage.master" %>
Line 3:  
  

 Source File:  /mech/resume.aspx    Line:  1

Comment: I'm going to try to upload onto local IIS server

Comment: I uploaded the website project (with the two sub-directories which contain web pages) onto the IIS server on my local server and it works fine.  I can access the pages in the root directory as well as the pages in the sub-directories.  I just cannot get the website to work when uploaded to server.

Comment: @Chris is not help to just say that you "cannot make it work". What error did you get ?

Comment: I know.  Sorry it took so long to get back.  I was playing around with the files some trying to get it to work.  I did eventually get the website to work properly on the server.  When I upload the website onto the local IIS server the following web.config file was created:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: I was not originally allowing directory browsing.  The original web.config file I was using looked like this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: So the website does work now.  I am very happy about this.  There is no sensitive data on the website ... however, if there was sensitive data on the website .. I know enabling directory browsing is extremely unsafe.  It would be nice to know if it is possible to access the web-pages in sub-directories without having to enable directory browsing.  Anyway, thanks so much Aristos for all the help!!!  It was a great help having someone to troubleshoot with!